# Type 'null' is not assignable to type ** in typesript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I developed sample class as follows. it register some data to database.

```
export class registerPricingTransactionInfo {

    private pricingTransaction:transactionArgument=null;

    constructor(pricingTransaction:transactionArgument){
        this.pricingTransaction = pricingTransaction;
        this.registerPricingTransactionInfo
    }

    private urlCode = new generateUrlCode(
        this.pricingTransaction.npServiceDivision,
        this.pricingTransaction.companyCode,
        this.pricingTransaction.shopBranchCode,
        this.pricingTransaction.shopRegistrationDateSeq,
        this.pricingTransaction.shopCode,
        this.pricingTransaction.npTransactionId).urlCode()
    
    private transaction:executeTransaction = {
        npServiceDivision       : this.pricingTransaction.npServiceDivision,
        shopCode                : this.pricingTransaction.shopCode,
        npTransactionId         : this.pricingTransaction.npTransactionId,
        companyCode             : this.pricingTransaction.companyCode,
      
    }


public  registerPricingTransactionInfo: RegisterPricingTransactionInfo = async () => {

        await getRepository(PricingTransaction)
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .insert()
            .into(PricingTransaction)
            .values([this.transaction])
            .execute()
return this.transaction;
}
```

But I encountered following error.

How can I initialize `pricingTransaction`? Thanks

`Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'transactionArgument'.`

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code. [Code samples](/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, *complete* and representative.

Comment: not the issue ... but what's point of the statement `this.registerPricingTransactionInfo` ... it does nothing

Comment: I intended to execute function when create its instance.  are there any wrong point of that .. ? I am totally novice of that, I would like to know the point. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Assign null to interface in angular 4](/q/49976073/90527)", "[Type null is not assignable to type IJobDetails (which is my interface)](/q/50703403/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

`pricingTransaction` should be declared like this:

```
private pricingTransaction: transactionArgument | null = null;
```

Or better yet in the constructor itself:

```js
    constructor(private pricingTransaction: transactionArgument){
        this.registerPricingTransactionInfo
    }
```